# How to rawWrite an Array!ubyte?

Tags: d

Some days ago I was writing a TAP file generator for ZX Spectrum. To write bytes incrementally into output I'd use streams on Delphi or C++, but D deprecated streams.

So I chose rawWrite. As for bytes storage, it was Array!uint **(correction: it was Array!ubyte)** from std.containers. But rawWrite can write only traditional arrays and not containers. And seems like there's no simple way to convert an Array to an array. *(using .array worked on Array!uint, but not on Array!ubyte)*

In the end I used a simple dynamic array, but it left a feeling of user-unfriendliness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always get an array out of your Array data using the *std.array.array* function like in the D code below:

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.stdio;
import std.range;
import std.container.array;

void main() {
  auto fn = "test.dat";
  // scope(exit) std.file.remove(fn);

  auto f = File(fn,"wb");
  Array!ubyte myarr = [ubyte(5), ubyte(4), ubyte(3), ubyte(2), ubyte(1)];
  f.rawWrite(myarr.array);
}
```

Save it to, say, arr2.d, compile and run:

```
dmd arr2.d && ./arr2
```

Let's verify that it wrote what we expect:

```
hexdump -C test.dat
00000000  05 04 03 02 01                                    |.....|
00000005
```

Comment: Correction: I used Array!ubyte then. If I try to use this code with ubyte, dmd writes: "cannot deduce function from argument types". I should change my question.

Answer (score 1):

`std.containers.array.Array` owns and fully encapsulates its data, and does not provide direct access to it. This is because it manages the data's lifetime, so any operation on the `Array` would invalidate any pointers to its interior data. Therefore, the only way to obtain the `Array`'s elements as a contiguous vector is to copy them, one by one, to e.g. a standard D array. The `std.array.array` function, which copies an arbitrary range to a D array, aids in this task:

```
import std.array;
import std.container.array;


Array!uint ci = [1, 2, 3];
uint[] ai = ci.array;
assert(ai == [1, 2, 3]);

Array!ubyte cb = [ubyte(1), ubyte(2), ubyte(3)];
ubyte[] ab = cb.array;
assert(ab == [ubyte(1), ubyte(2), ubyte(3)]);
```

At this point, this doesn't seem considerably advantageous to writing the `Array` elements directly to a file, or avoiding the use of `Array` entirely.